# How to pass 2D Vector from Rust to Fortran with FFI?

Tags: rust, fortran, ffi

I'm trying to pass a 2D f64 vector (Vec<Vec>) from Rust to a Fortran function. I've being using 1D vectors with other Fortran functions using .as_mut_ptr().

I'm not entirely sure how to post a minimal working example for something like this but here we go:

```
extern "C" {
    fn fortran1_(
        vector: *mut f64,
        length1: *const uint32_t
    );

    fn fortran2_(
        vector: *mut f64, 
        length1: *const uint32_t, 
        length2: *const uint32_t
    );
}

pub fn fortran1(
    length1: u32
) -> Vec<f64>{
    let mut vector = vec![0_f64; length1];
    unsafe{
        fortran1_(
            vector.as_mut_ptr(),
            &length1)
    }
    return vector;
}

pub fn fortran2(
    length1: u32, 
    length2: u32
)-> Vec<Vec<f64>>{
    let mut vector = vec![vec![0_f64; length1]; length2];
    unsafe{
        fortran2_(vector.as_mut_ptr(), 
        &length1, 
        &length2)
    }
    return vector;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a 1D array, and working with it _as if_ it were multidimensional, or use an [`ndarray` library](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/index.html). A `Vec` doesn't store its elements in-line, meaning that while data from each inner array _is_ contiguous, the inner arrays are not contiguous with each other. In other words, you can't get to the second vector by indexing or pointer arithmetic, since there isn't a consistent stride pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of mismatches between your rust `Vec<Vec<_>>` representation and Fortran's standard data model.

Fortran expects 2-d arrays to be laid out in a contiguous slice of `f64`, but `Vec<Vec<_>>` puts each of its rows ln separate heap allocations.

Fortran indices are 1-based, but `Vec` are 0-based.

You would be best off implementing a `struct Fortran2d<T> { vec: Vec<T>, rows: usize, cols:usize, }` and implement methods on that emulating Fortran indexing. I think that would be least painful.

```
impl Fortran2d<T> {
    /// maps fortran style 2d index to internal vec index
    fn index(&self, c: usize, r: usize) -> usize {
        assert!(c > 0 && c <= self.cols);
        assert!(r > 0 && r <= self.rows);
        (c - 1) + (r - 1) * self.cols
   }
}
```

Comment: Nit: "Fortran indices are 1-based" ... the default is 1-based, but Fortran allows you to use any integer base you want.